# use multiple $(function() with ajax live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a live search. When i open up the page i want to run `$(function() {`. This run the ajax once and all the output shown up. But i want that it is also updating the page when i type in the searchbox(thats why i used this `$('#search').keyup(function(){`). AND i want that it update the page also when i press one of the checkboxes which add some other values to the livesearch(`$('.btn').click(function(){`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
$('#search').keyup(function(){
   var search = $(this).val();
   console.log("Input: " + search);
$('.btn').click(function(){
   let val1 = getval1();
   let val2 = getval2();
   let val3 = getval3();
   let val4 = getval4();
   console.log(val1 + val2 + val3 + val4)
$.ajax({
    url:"search.php",
    method:"post",
    data:{
       search:search,
       val1:val1,
       val2:val2,
       val3:val3,
       val4:val4,
       },
       success:function(data){
          $('#output').html(data);
       }
});
});
});
});
```

Comment: You can add a `console.log(search, val1, val2, val3, val4);` last in that function and check the browsers console (under development tools) to see if you get any output on key up.

Comment: i dont know how to use the console.log statement. Can you make a code snipped which work with the file?

Comment: This would be the perfect moment to learn it.

Comment: I just gave you a code snippet. Take what I wrote in my comment (the console.log()) and put it in the line after `let val4 = getval4();`

Comment: You have an issue though. Your `load_data()` function expects an argument (the `query`) but you never pass any argument to that function when you call it.

Comment: u missunderstand me. i get an output but the output updates only when i touch the searchbar. when i enter something to the other variables nothing changed, but when i write a letter in the searchbar it updates and when i remove it its updated for only the other variable. the problem is not that the ajax isnt sending the values. it is not updating.

Comment: you are using functions in the wrong way. And events binding too

Comment: than please tell me how its right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
search_data()
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    search_data()
});
$('.btn').click(function(){
    search_data()
});
});
function search_data(query){
    var search = $('#search').val();
    let val1 = getval1();
    let val2 = getval2();
    let val3 = getval3();
    let val4 = getval4();
    $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{
            query:query,
            search:search,
            val1:val1,
            val2:val2,
            val3:val3,
            val4:val4,
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#output').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//page completed loading
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
    //user typed something 
        var search = $(this).val();
        let val1 = getval1();
        let val2 = getval2();
        let val3 = getval3();
        let val4 = getval4();
        //let's retrieve values
        $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{
                query:query,
                search:search,
                val1:val1,
                val2:val2,
                val3:val3,
                val4:val4
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#output').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

That is enough. You don't even need to use click event since it will fire on each type. Otherwise you can use the click instead of the keyup and it will fire on button click.
Each time you will type something into #search, you will check the value of the other fields too. I'm curious to see what is inside each getval fucntion beacuse probably they can be replaced by something simpler (btw no need for four different functions imho)

Note: `$(document).ready(){};` is used to tell the browser to wait the full page to be loaded before executing the code. You will have one of these only in your page with all the js inside. The functions you define (like when you do

```
function getval1(){
//your function here
}
```

don't need to be inside the document ready statement

Comment: but my search isnt updating when i enter another inforamtion which. there are some buttons and a search bar. tahts why i used `$('#search').keyup(function(){` and `$('#btn').click(function(){`